# Regex: Exclude optional term from match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to draft a regex that will match everything before the first `:` in a string, and exclude a specific term in the text right before the `:` if found. Call the term `Grumble`.

I want to match `Foo` in the string `Foo: Bars`.

I want to match `Foo fuzz` in `Foo fuzz Grumble: Bars and moar bars`.

I tried the pattern `^.*(?=(Grumble)?:)`, **but it includes `Grumble` in the match in the second example above.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a tempered `[^:]`:

```
^([^:](?!Grumble))*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/I3nhdK/1)

Explanation:

- `^` Assert beginning of input string
- `(` Open a grouping

  - `[^:]` Any character except `:`
  - `(?!Grumble)` That's not followed by word `Grumble`
- `)*` As much as possible

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^.*?(?=Grumble|:)
```

- `.*?` non-greedy match for any character
- `(?=Grumble|:)` denotes a positive lookahead with two conditions

  - if `Grumble` is found then only capture until before `Grumble`
  - or if `:` is found then only capture until before `:`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j5Q84k/2)

**EDIT:** Mis-interpreted the OP's ask a tiny bit. Thanks @revo for the clarification

Comment: Fails on `Foo fuzz Grumble bar: Bars and more bars`

Comment: Yes, that's right but I think the OP wants it to work differently _only if_ Grumble is right before `:`

Comment: *...specific term in the text **before** the `:`*... I don't read it as *right before*.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. Looks like I mis-read it. Thanks! Updated the answer